# redux state don't send when use react-navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, jsx, react-navigation

i am using react-navigation and redux in react-native.when i just used redux, the states can send to child by redux. but it don't work when i add react-navigation.

my navigation.js

```jsx
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './modules/home/views/Home'
export const StackRouter = StackNavigator({
    Main: {screen: Home},
    initialRouteName: {screen: Home}
});
const firstAction = StackRouter.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Main');
const tempNavState = StackRouter.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);
const initialNavState = StackRouter.router.getStateForAction(
    firstAction,
    tempNavState
);
//navigationreducer
export const stackReducer = (state=initialNavState,action) => {
    debugger
    const newState = StackRouter.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return newState || state;
};
```

my store.js

```jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import  { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, combineReducers, bindActionCreators, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import {addNavigationHelpers} from 'react-navigation'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import {StackRouter, stackReducer} from './router'
import home from './modules/home';   



//routerConmponent
class RouterAppWithState extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <StackRouter navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                state: this.props.router,
            })} />
        );
    }
}


//all reducer
const reducer = combineReducers({
    home: home.reducer,
    router: stackReducer,

});

const mapActionToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        home_actions: bindActionCreators(home.actions, dispatch)
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    debugger;
    return state
};



//connect redux and navigation
const StoreApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(RouterAppWithState);

const store = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore)(reducer);

export default class RootApp extends Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <StoreApp />
            </Provider>
        )
    }

}
```

my home.js ,just import actions and reducers, and export the module

```jsx
import actions from './store/actions';
import reducer from './store/reducer'

export default {
    actions,
    reducer
}
```

my reducers

```jsx
export default(state=states, action) => {
    let newState = {...state};
    switch (action.type){
        case TYPES.ADD_COUNT: newState.count = state.count+1;break;
        default: break;
    }
    return newState
};
```

my actions

```jsx
const add_count = () => {
    console.log('add');
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: TYPES.ADD_COUNT});
        await new Promise((resolve) => {setTimeout(() => {resolve()} , 3000)});
        dispatch({type: TYPES.ADD_COUNT});
    };
};



export default {
    add_count
}
```

my view Home.js

```jsx
import React, {Component, StyleSheet} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    // static contextTypes = {
    //     navigation: React.PropTypes.Object
    // };
    render() {
        debugger
        const {add_count} = this.props.home_actions;
        const {count} = this.props.home;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text >{count}</Text>
                <Button onPress={add_count} title={'add count'}/>
                {/*<Button onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('live')}} title={'live'}/>*/}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

In Home.js function render, this.props is

```jsx
{
navigation: Object,
screenProps: undefined
}
```

has not states in redux. but without react-navigation, this.props is

```jsx
{
home: Object,
home_actions: Object
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because now the `StackRouter` is controlling the rendering of your `Home` page. The router only pass down a prop called `navigation` and whatever you pass down from `screenProps`.

There are two ways that you can achieve a similar behavior as before:

1) In `RouterAppWithState`'s render function, pass down `this.props` into `screenProps` like this

```
<StackRouter navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
            state: this.props.router,
        })}
  screenProps={this.props}
/>
```

2) (**recommended**) The other way is to directly use `connect` on your home page to connect your `Home` component to the store and access `home` specific part of the store. i.e. `connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)`

Comment: that's amazing！！！i succeeded in solving my problem, and thank you very much

Comment: It'd be pretty help to show what you mean by using multiple connects via code.

Comment: @BoomerRogers I think thats from one of my previous edit? So basically, if you want to subscribe to changes, you can connect you component using connect()(YourComponent) and you can do this for any component that needs something from the store. It doesn’t have to be just the root level component that connects to the redux store. This does mean that you need to be more mindful of what is triggering a re-render to avoid unnecessary rendering if you are connecting both the component and one of its descendent.